# bundle only selected libraries in packrat

Tags: r, packrat

I am trying to move a project from local machine to a server with no internet access and no privilege to install libraries. 
The server is already installed with many of the libraries.

For my current project the are some libraries and dependencies which are not available on server.

So, I am trying to use packrat to bundle and move the project to server.
Now, the bundle size is becoming huge and others. I want to bundle only packages that are not available on server. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a project with all your libraries and work, load packrat library and call function bundle()

```
library(packrat)
bundle()
```

This create a projname.tar.gz file

Copy this file and paste on your server project folder and call unbundle function as follows, bundle = name of your bundle and "." means unbundle here in that folder

```
library(packrat)
unbundle(bundle="packlib.tar.gz",where=".")
```

Comment: This will create a huge file. I want bundle only selected packages.

Comment: I created a bundle 14 libraries with work of 3 ggplots and randomForest model, and model selection from 8 models, gave me 13.7mb